# How to change case of file names recursive?

Tags: linux, file, case

I need to set case of all files to lowercase:

```
directory11
       subdirectory11
             subdirectory21
                 File1
                 File2
                 ...
                 Filen
directory21
       subdirectory21
             subdirectory21
                 File1
                 File2
                 ...
                 Filen
..............................................


directory11
       subdirectory11
             subdirectory21
                 file1
                 file2
                 ...
                 filen
directory21
       subdirectory21
             subdirectory21
                 file1
                 file2
                 ...
                 filen
..............................................
```

Does it possible with linux command? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible options is using `tr` to change the case. Find all the files using `find` in the directory. Create the upper file name string using `tr` & use `mv` to rename. Something on these lines:

```
while read OLD_FILENAME
do
    NEW_FILENAME=`echo "$OLD_FILENAME"|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
    mv -v "$OLD_FILENAME" "$NEW_FILENAME"
done < <(find directory_name -type f)
```

Or if you want interactive mode for `mv` i.e ask for replacement confirmation use something on these lines:

```
(
IFS=$'\n'
for OLD_FILENAME in $(find directory_name -type f)
do
   NEW_FILENAME=`echo "$OLD_FILENAME"|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
   mv -vi "$OLD_FILENAME" "$NEW_FILENAME"
done
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to using `rename(1)` command :

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' **
```

`**` mean recursive if you are using bash4 and `globstar` setting :

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Moreover, this is the perl version of `rename`. If you type

```
file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you see `ELF`, you have the wrong one, see `prename`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```